# Laravel 5.1 connect to SQL Server using centos 6 and PHP 5.6

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5.1

I used the following link to make a connection to a SQL database using Laravel 5.1: 
http://jacksondean.net/connecting-to-microsoft-sql-server-with-php-from-centos-6-x7-x/

I followed each step and during the installation everything went good, but Laravel uses the `lastInsertId` function apparently.
 When I run my project I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[IM001]: Driver does not support this function: driver does not support lastInsertId()

I am using a Centos 6.7 server with PHP 5.6 and Laravel version 5.1 for the project.

Could someone help me out with this error?

Comment: Which driver are you using?

Comment: I am using this driver: `SQL Server Native Client 11.0`, as described in the link

Comment: what's the value you are using on your .env file for "DB_CONNECTION" variable? You should use `DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv`